# Joint distribution between the result of a dice and the max between two throwns of a dice

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

A dice has been thrown $2$ times. Let $X$ be the result of the first thrown, and $Y$ the max between the first and the second thrown. Find the joint distribution of $(X,Y)$ and the marginal distributions of $X$ and $Y$.

My attempt was to observe that $P(X=x,Y=y)=P(Y=y \mid X=x)P(X=x)$, and then observe that $P(Y=y \mid X=x)$ is the probability that $y$ is the maximum knowing that $x$ was the result of the first thrown, so:
$$P(Y=y \mid X=1)P(X=1)=\dfrac{1}{6} \cdot \dfrac{1}{6}\\
P(Y=y \mid X=2)P(X=2)=\dfrac{1}{5} \cdot \dfrac{1}{6}\\
P(Y=y \mid X=3)P(X=3)=\dfrac{1}{4} \cdot \dfrac{1}{6}\\
P(Y=y \mid X=4)P(X=4)=\dfrac{1}{3} \cdot \dfrac{1}{6}\\
P(Y=y \mid X=5)P(X=5)=\dfrac{1}{2} \cdot \dfrac{1}{6}\\
P(Y=y \mid X=6)P(X=6)=1 \cdot \dfrac{1}{6}\\$$
So generally we could write $p_{X,Y}(x,y)=P(X=x,Y=y)=\dfrac{1}{6}\cdot \dfrac{1}{6-x+1}\mathbb{1}_{\{y\ge x\}}(x,y)$.
But this doesn't seem to work since when I try to do the marginal distribution of $X$ I obtain:
$$p_X(x)=\sum_{y=1}^{6}p_{X,Y}(x,y)=\dfrac{1}{6}\sum_{y=1}^6\dfrac{1}{6-x+1}\mathbb{1}_{\{y \ge x\}}(x,y)=\dfrac{1}{6}\left(\dfrac{1}{6}+\dfrac{1}{6}+\dfrac{1}{5}+\dfrac{1}{6}+\dfrac{1}{5}+\dfrac{1}{4}+\dots\right)$$
That is different from $p_X(x)=1/6$, where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maximum of the two dice can *not* be *less than* the result of first die.

Let $Z$ be the result of the second die.  Consider what values of $Z$ are needed to witness the event $X=x, Y=y$ ?  Divide into three cases.

- When $y<x$ ,there is no result of the second die that may produce the event.  $\mathsf P(X=x,Y=y)\mathbf 1_{y<x}=0$
- When $y>x$, then the second die needs to equal the maximum.  $\mathsf P(X=x,Y=y)\mathbf 1_{x<y}=\mathsf P(X=x, Z=y)\mathbf 1_{x<y}$
- When $x=y$, then the second die needs to be at most equal to that. $\mathsf P(X=x,Y=y)\mathbf 1_{x=y}=\mathsf P(X=x, Z\leq x)\mathbf 1_{x=y}$

Hence $p(x,y)~{=~\mathsf P(X=x, Y=y)\\ =~ \mathsf P(X=x)\mathbf 1_{1\leq x\leq 6}\left(\mathsf P(Z\leq x)\mathbf 1_{x=y}+\mathsf P(Z=y)\mathbf 1_{x<y\leq 6}\right)\\=~\left(\tfrac x{36}\mathbf 1_{1\leq x=y\leq 6}+\tfrac 1{36}\mathbf 1_{1\leq x<y\leq 6}\right)}$

Now use this to evaluate $p(x)=\sum_{y=x}^6 p(x,y)$

Answer (score 2):

You assumed that conditional probability $P(Y=y|X=x)$ is equal for all $y>x$, which is not true. What is probability that $Y=6$, given that $X=5$? Only 1/6. Because only when the second dice is 6, which happens 1/6 of the time, we will get $Y=6$.

Thus, the joint distribution is:
$$
p(x,y) = \frac16\times\begin{cases}
0& x>y,\\
x/6 & x=y,\\
1/6& x<y
\end{cases}
$$